# Issues when exporting/zonal statistics rasters from .tif and .nc files

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff, zonal-statistics

I am trying to aggregate at a 0.1º cell level, using zonal statistics, two variables that come from two different raster files (one in .tif, other in .nc format, links [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1yxkn17y7cplchs/MOD13Q1_2000-02-18.250m_16_days_NDVI.tif?dl=0) and [here](http://digital.csic.es/bitstream/10261/153475/3/spei01.nc)).

Both seem to work fine in the R raster environment as, by loading and plotting them with

```
library(ncdf4)
r.works <- raster::raster('MOD13Q1_2000-02-18.250m_16_days_NDVI.tif')
r.dwork <- brick("spei01.nc") #this is a multilayer stack

rasterVis::levelplot(r.works)
rasterVis::levelplot(r.dwork[[1]]) #plot just the first layer
```

I obtain clear graphs, respectively attached. However, if I use the [ZonalPipe](http://www.guru-gis.net/efficient-zonal-statistics-using-r-and-gdal/) function to do fast zonal statistics within a [grid](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gv8qmx1bgrti4mr/grid.rdata?dl=0), I obtain a lot of NA values for the latter (not shown/plotted here for neatness), even though both rasters cover 100% of the grid of interest. I obviously set both rasters' crs equal to the grid's one before doing zonal stats. I thus investigated both objects and they seem to differ

```
> r.works
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 5000, 10444, 52220000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)
extent      : -26.10815, 78.33185, -10, 40  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : /Users/hannesmueller/Documents/NDVI Data/MOD13Q1_2000-02-18.250m_16_days_NDVI.tif 
names       : MOD13Q1_2000.02.18.250m_16_days_NDVI 
values      : -32768, 32767  (min, max)

> r.dwork[[1]]
class       : RasterLayer 
band        : 1  (of  1380  bands)
dimensions  : 360, 720, 259200  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : /Users/hannesmueller/Dropbox/Locus Project Augustin Lavinia Bruno/gis data/spei/spei01.nc 
names       : X1901.01.16 
z-value     : 1901-01-16 
zvar        : spei
```

in the `band` element of the second layer, whose meaning I do not understand. Finally, I exported them with

```
writeRaster(r.works, "rworks", format = "GTiff")
writeRaster(r.dwork, "rdwork", format = "GTiff")
```

and the [former](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kr5o91ed7aw5b2a/rworks.tif?dl=0) opens perfectly in a GIS software, whereas the [latter](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0eqdrfc2jtxyv2j/rdwork.tif?dl=0) does not. That makes me very suspicious about the second raster, which was obtained with the .nc file. Am I importing it into R wrongly and/or missing any step when using zonal statistics/exporting it as geotiffs?

[image: plot of r.work]
[image: plot of r.dwork]

Comment: When you say you set the crs to match, did you actually reproject one raster to match the other, or just alter the crs directly with e.g. `crs(x) <- value`?

Comment: I did set as you mentioned, using ``crs(x) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")``, which is the CRS of the polygon I am trying to aggregate the data in. But beyond the aggregation, it seems very weird to me that exporting the raster obtained from the .nc stack does not provide a 'readable' raster in a GIS software. Any hints on that?

Answer (score 1):

Per your comment above, you have not actually reprojected your rasters. `crs()` is essentially a metadata editing and reporting function, but its documentation is brief so many people don't realise at first. To alter the actual data, you need to use `projectRaster()` instead. Your GIS is most likely confused about a mismatch between the claimed CRS and the actual data.

For large rasters, `projectRaster()` can be slow. You might consider using GDALwarp instead. If you have GDAL installed and on your system path, you can call it in R using `system2()`, e.g.

```
library(raster)

# just some random data i have in EPSG:3577
test <- raster('C:/DATA/rmap2.tif') 

# gdalwarp docs - http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html
test_4326 <- system2('gdalwarp',
                     args = c(
                       # source projection (proj4 string, mind the quotes)
                       '-s_srs', paste0('"', crs(test), '"'),
                       # desired projection (EPSG code)
                       '-t_srs', 'EPSG:4326',
                       # resampling method
                        '-r', 'bilinear',
                       # src file - can't just pass in R object, must refer to on disk file
                       test@file@name,
                       # dest file - must also be on disk
                       file.path('C:', 'data', 'test_4326.tif')))

test_4326 <- raster(file.path('C:', 'data', 'test_4326.tif'))
```

Comment: Reprojecting the raster as you mentioned (either with ``projectRaster()`` or with GDALwarp does not seem to solve my issue of problems with the final exported tif file. I noticed that, if I substitute the many ``NA``values in the raster with 0es, I manage to export it well. Nevertheless, if running zonal stats, I get the same problem of 98% of my cells with ``NA``.

Comment: hmm ok. The only other problem I can see is that the cells in your second grid are 0.5 x 0.5 degree but you're trying to 'aggregate' to a smaller size, 0.1 x 0.1 degree. The zonal stats function is probably confused as a result - things would be going pear-shaped at the use of `crop()`. That zonal stats script is...not exactly robust, although its certainly well-intended. You should `raster::disaggregate()` `r.dwork`.

Comment: That is actually my guess here. I did aggregation at coarser spatial levels and it seems to work.